# The formation of West Mata

Tags: volcanology, plate-tectonics

I was wondering if anyone knows how the formation of the [West Mata volcano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Mata) came to be? I was reading that a lot of underwater volcanoes were formed by convergent boundary. Is this how West Mata was created?